# 2021 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

[Moderator election #5](https://physics.stackexchange.com/election/5) on Physics has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderators are:

[image: Buzz]

[image: SuperCiocia]

They will be joining [the existing crew](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/election/5) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5763439621308416).

Comment: Best wishes Buzz and SuperCiocia, and I thank you both for stepping up and volunteering!

Answer (score 22):

[image]

Comment: Congratulations! And thanks for stepping up!

Answer (score 22):

Thank you.  I appreciate the community's show of faith in me.

I am familiarizing myself with all the new controls.

[image: Buzz]

Comment: Add I said to SuperCiocia, Congratulations! And thanks for stepping up!

Answer (score 16):

I would like to thank everyone who put their name forward.  It is testament to the quality of all contributors to this forum that once again I felt completely confident that any outcome would result in an outstanding moderation team.